# How can i check multiple lines text in java regex?

Tags: java, regex

I want to check multiple lines of text in Java regular expression. But it is always showing false result. Can anyone explain me why?

For example:

```
11  12
11  12
11  12
```

For testing those lines, I am using `11  12\r?\n+`. It is working fine in rubular regular expression checker but failing in http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html. Another alternatives I tried was `(11  12.\r?\n){3,7}`, which is working fine in rubular regex check but failed in regexplanet Java. Can anyone tell me how can check this type of regular expression having repeating pattern?

Comment: I doubt that they are working correctly in Rubular. Both patterns have fundamental errors in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
11 12\r?\n+
```

matches `11 12`, followed by an optional carriage return, followed by one or more line feeds (without carriage returns). This is obviously not what you want.

```
(11 12.\r?\n){3,7}
```

matches `11 12`, followed by one additional character except newlines, followed by an optional CR and a line feed; all of this is repeated 3 to 7 times. So the dot is wrong here. Use this instead:

```
(11 12\r?\n){3,7}
```

Finally, be aware that you usually need to double backslashes in a Java regex because of string escaping rules (although in this particular case, you'll be alright because `\r` and `\n` happen to work as string escapes, too):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(11 12\r?\n){3,7}");  // works the same as
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(11 12\\r?\\n){3,7}");
```

Comment: And i am using double slash because i am using it in my java testing tool where it  is needed to put extra backslash

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? [It's working here](http://regex101.com/r/wG7mJ5), for example.

Comment: That site doesn't allow multiline input strings, and it doesn't seem to allow permalinks. The regex *is* correct (it does require each line to end in a linefeed, in case that's your problem). You don't need double backslashes here, either (but they don't hurt).